# After upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.4, unable to connect from localhost

Tags: linux, debian, postgresql

I have recently upgraded from Debian 7 to Debian 8 and from PostgreSQL 9.1 to 9.4. I am not able to connect to my database server even from pgAdmin III on localhost.

I have in my postgresql.conf the port as 5433 and the listen_address as "*".

In pg_hba.conf, I have the following lines:
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
host all all ::1/128 md5

Nonetheless, I get the following error when I try to connect:

[image]

What configuration have I not yet configured? I believe I went through the same procedure in the config files as when I set up in 9.1, but it is not working.

Comment: What says `netstat -anp | grep 5433` ?

Comment: @krisFR no output

Comment: So what says `netstat -anp | grep -i postgre` ?

Comment: No output. I made sure it was started first too.

Comment: It is not started.

Comment: I'm running /etc/init.d/postgresql start and getting [ ok ] Starting postgresql (via systemctl): postgresql.service.

Comment: Run `pg_lsclusters`. Presumably it will indicate that no postgres cluster (=instance) is online or defined. That would be because you didn't `pg_upgradecluster` or otherwise dump/reload from 9.1 to 9.4

Answer (score 0):

The message you highlighted on the screenshot clearly states that the server did not start. Your `pg_hba.conf` looks syntactically correct, so I doubt it is the issue. You need to examine the logs. Most probably you forgot to perform the upgrade and the server refuses to start upon detecting old data format.

You should check the logs for something like the following:

```
Sep 02 18:11:03 localhost.localdomain postgresql-check-db-dir[30673]: An old version of the database format was found.
Sep 02 18:11:03 localhost.localdomain postgresql-check-db-dir[30673]: Use "postgresql-setup --upgrade" to upgrade to version 9.4.
```

If this is indeed the case then you need to run:

```
postgresql-setup --upgrade
```